# How can I make a 2D Sprite bleed/glow colors at a particular spot?

Tags: unity

I am trying to make a gauge glow over the color it is at.  For example, in the image below, when the needle is pointing at the red, the red is glowing.  When it is pointing at the green, then the green is glowing.  I want to replicate this:

[image][image]

My gauge will be on a gradient, so I cannot just color a particular segment.  (There are no segments.)  I am working with 2D sprites.  I have looked into the [Bloom](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-BloomOptimized.html) asset as suggested [here](http://www.samuraifight.com/2015/09/12/glow-in-unity-5/), but I have been met with nothing but failures.  (Probably because that guide is for 3D.)

How can I take the color at a particular position and make it bleed/glow like in the images above?

Comment: This looks like they might just be drawing a second sprite on top, with additive blending. The falloff looks quite similar to the radial gradient of the default Unity particle texture, tinted to the appropriate colour for the current gauge readout and positioned correspondingly. Have you tried a simple approach like this?

Comment: @DMGregory I have not.  The reason being I won't know what pixel color I am currently pointing at.  (My gauge's color is on a gradient, instead of hard color shifts.)  Good thought though.  Maybe I can adapt it to work for my situation.

Comment: "I won't know what pixel color I am currently pointing at" - why not? It's your game, not some mystery box you've never looked inside. If your colours are on a gradient curve, sample the curves at the interpolator index you want to read. If they're coming from a texture, you can [read a pixel from it with GetPixel](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixel.html). If they're coming from layered scene geometry you can use a RenderTexture or GrabPass. Show us more of your setup and we can demonstrate more specifically.